# Find scriptable object by pre-assigned variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making an endless runner where you are a fish avoiding the dangerous ocean on their way to school. To make it endless and not level based, I have decided on taking the easy way out and used a form of module-based generation where I load mini level pieces directly next to each other.

To achieve this, I have created the modules as scriptable objects and created a ModuleManager script to generate them smoothly.

To pick out specific modules, I created a

```
public List<Module> modules = new List<Module>();
```

Now I need to figure out how to get a certain module out of the list given the value of a certain variable like `difficulty` assigned in the module scriptable object script.

Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use e.g. [LINQ FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.6) like e.g.

```c#
using System.Linq;

//...

public Module GetByDifficulty(int difficulty)
{
    return modules.FirstOrDefault(m => m.difficuty == difficulty));
}
```

if the `difficulty` is not unique you'll get the first match in the list. If no match is found you'll get the default value (for classes usually `null`).

---

Basically it's a shortcuts for using

```c#
public Module GetByDifficulty(int difficulty)
{
    foreach(var m in modules)
    {
        if(m.difficulty == difficulty) return m;
    }
    return null;
}
```

if you are more confident using this than stick with it.